# How to create a set amount of panels and put a user control in each one?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms, user-controls

I am trying to dynamically create a number of panels each with a user control in it based on the number of objects in a list, but for some reason when I execute the code below nothing shows up. Is my approach completely inaccurate or am I missing something small. Thank you in advance for your help.

```
            foreach (Workshop workshop in Organization.GetAvailableWorkshops())
            {
                Panel panel = new Panel();
                panel.Controls.Clear();
                var myControl = new UCWorkshopOverview(workshop);
                panel.Controls.Add(myControl);
            }
```

Comment: If it is a new panel, `panel.Controls.Clear();` will do nothing. You must add the panel to the form or to some parent control. `this.Controls.Add(panel);` or `stackPanel1.Controls.Add(panel)` or something like this.

Comment: Do you already have a Panel inside a Form or do you actually need to also create a new Panel container? If you need a new Panel, then you of course also need to add the Panel to an existing Container (the Form or another Container). -- That `panel.Controls.Clear();` (as noted, useless here) may suggest that you already have a Panel and you're trying to add a new UserControl to it while *removing* (not really) the previous content. Specify what's what.

Comment: @Jimi I want to add a new panel for each element in my list

Comment: Do you want to add a new Panel to what container? The Form? Something else? If the Form, then see the first comment. Otherwise, just add the new Panels to the `Controls` collection of the actual existing Container (another Panel, a TableLayoutPanel, whatever), the same way you're adding UserControls to your Panels.